# SQL Query - Select Customers equal or less than a certain age

Tags: sql

I am trying to SELECT from a CUSTOMERS table where I have to write a script to get all clients who are 45 years and younger on the ID Number column(The column is a South African 13 number digits and it is a VARCHAR), on the WHERE clause.

```sql
SELECT 
    Customers.ID, Customers.lastName, Customers.firstName
FROM 
    CUSTOMERS
WHERE ID <= DATEADD(yy, -45, GETDATE())
```

Comment: How could you compare a 13 digit number with age?? Are you sure there isn't another column in the table that has the age?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? When asking SQL questions, you should always tag the request with your DBMS in order to get answers working for you. Then, a number is not a date. And an ID is usually a mere technical code with no meaning. And if its a number, why is it not stored as a number, but as a string? There does exist a standard numbering for datetimes called "Unix time", but this is usually nine or ten digits.

Answer (score -1):

Could you provide an example of the dataset?  From a first glance, DATEADD produces a DATE, not a number or varchar.  Since the ID is a VARCHAR you must cast that to the same type that DATEADD produces.